# Регулярные выражения java. Входная строка содержит матрицу

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка с записанной матрицей 0,0,2;0,0,4;1,0,0
нужно вычленить из неё числовые значения (могут быть как int так и с плавающей точкой) и записать в List, где внутренний это значения по горизонтали, а внешний это строки матрицы. (размерность заранее не известна)

Помогите подобрать регулярное выражения для разделения матрицы вначале на строки, а затем по значениям.
я пробовал так

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^|;(.);|$");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while(matcher.find()){
                Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(\\d*.\\d*|\\d*)");
                Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(line);
                while(matcher2.find()){
                    value_x.add((T)matcher2.group());
                }
                value.add(value_x);
                value_x.clear();
            }
            sb.add(value);
            value.clear();
        }
```

Comment: ну разделите сначала это все по строкам, и потом каждую строку по числам.

Answer (score 0):

Тут задача простая. Можно использовать функцию разбиения строки

```
String Str = new String("0,0,2,4;0.5,0.4,5,4;1.1,0,0,6");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();  
            for (String retval : Str.split(";")) {
                ArrayList<Float> row = new  ArrayList<Float>();
                for (String val : retval.split(",")) {
                    row.add(Float.valueOf(val.trim()).floatValue());
            }
            matrix.add(row);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал такой метод:

```
public static <T extends Number> List<List<T>> getMatrix(String str, Class<T> numClass) {
    if (!numClass.getPackageName().startsWith("java.lang")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Number class " + numClass.getCanonicalName());
    }
    List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Method valueMethod = numClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
        for (StringTokenizer stLines = new StringTokenizer(str, ";"); stLines.hasMoreTokens();) {
            String line = stLines.nextToken();
            List<T> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ","); st.hasMoreTokens();) {
                String token = st.nextToken();
                lineList.add((T) valueMethod.invoke(null, token));
            }
            list.add(lineList);
        }
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
    String matrixStr = "0.3, 0, 2; 0, 0, 4; 1, 0, 0";
    List<List<Integer>> list = getMatrix(matrixStr, Integer.class);
    System.out.println(list);
```